# How to handle DB Concurrency issues using EF5.0 Code first approach?

Tags: entity-framework-5

Is there any standard way to handle the **concurrency problems** (when 2 users performing delete & update operations at the same time) using **Entity Framework 5.0 code first approach**?

please any one help me how to handle the concurrency issues using EF5.0 with example.

thanks,

sampath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried catching the [`OptimisticConcurrencyException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.optimisticconcurrencyexception.aspx)?

See this example: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application